# proFTPd + tls authentificatin issue

Tags: authentication, ssl, proftpd

Can't get in my ftp server. I use proftpd 1.3.4a with mod_tls/2.4.3.

I suspect a mistake lies it the **TLSOptions** directive

```
TLSEngine                        on
TLSLog                           /var/log/proftpd/tls.log
TLSProtocol                      SSLv23
TLSRSACertificateFile            /etc/proftpd/ssl/proftpd.cert.pem
TLSRSACertificateKeyFile         /etc/proftpd/ssl/proftpd.key.pem
TLSOptions                       NoCertRequest EnableDiags NoSessionReuseRequired
TLSVerifyClient                  off
TLSRequired                      on
```

**tls.log** said this when I was trying to connect

```
Ноя 02 17:19:24 mod_tls/2.4.3[14333]: TLSOption EnableDiags enabled, setting diagnostics callback
Ноя 02 17:19:24 mod_tls/2.4.3[14333]: using default OpenSSL verification locations (see $SSL_CERT_DIR environment variable)
Ноя 02 17:19:24 mod_tls/2.4.3[14333]: SSL/TLS required but absent for authentication, denying USER command
Ноя 02 17:19:24 mod_tls/2.4.3[14333]: [stat]: SSL sessions attempted: 0
Ноя 02 17:19:24 mod_tls/2.4.3[14333]: [stat]: SSL sessions established: 0
Ноя 02 17:19:24 mod_tls/2.4.3[14333]: [stat]: SSL sessions renegotiated: 0
Ноя 02 17:19:24 mod_tls/2.4.3[14333]: [stat]: SSL sessions resumed: 0
Ноя 02 17:19:24 mod_tls/2.4.3[14333]: [stat]: SSL sessions in cache: 0
Ноя 02 17:19:24 mod_tls/2.4.3[14333]: [stat]: SSL session cache hits: 0
Ноя 02 17:19:24 mod_tls/2.4.3[14333]: [stat]: SSL session cache misses: 0
Ноя 02 17:19:24 mod_tls/2.4.3[14333]: [stat]: SSL session cache timeouts: 0
Ноя 02 17:19:24 mod_tls/2.4.3[14333]: [stat]: SSL session cache size exceeded: 0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
TLSRequired                      on
....
SSL/TLS required but absent for authentication, denying USER command
```

I would suspect that the you are not using SSL/TLS to connect to the server. But you allow authentication only when done over SSL/TLS. Check the settings in your ftp client that you actually use SSL/TLS.

Comment: I switched off  this ssl availability of client. But Filezilla can work with FTP-S in explicit view. Still can't get in (

Comment: You set TLSRequired to on, which means that proftpd will not accept unencrypted connections (which also means no unencrypted authentication), see [documentation](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_TLSRequired.html). Thus the client must enable TLS (with AUTH TLS) before submitting the USER command.